# Invalid implicit conversion from address payable to bytes memory requested. This function requires a single bytes argument

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, keccak

```
function setBasicDetails(string memory _registrationNo,
                             string memory _farmerName,
                             string memory _farmAddress,
                             string memory _exporterName,
                             string memory _importerName
                             
                            ) public onlyAuthCaller returns(address) {
        
        uint tmpData = uint(keccak256(msg.sender));
        address batchNo = address(tmpData);
        
        basicDetailsData.registrationNo = _registrationNo;
        basicDetailsData.farmerName = _farmerName;
        basicDetailsData.farmAddress = _farmAddress;
        basicDetailsData.exporterName = _exporterName;
        basicDetailsData.importerName = _importerName;
        
        batchBasicDetails[batchNo] = basicDetailsData;
        
        nextAction[batchNo] = 'FARM_INSPECTION';   
        
        
        return batchNo;
    }
```

this is my solidity function code and i have error here's code

```
uint tmpData = uint(keccak256(msg.sender));
        address batchNo = address(tmpData);
```

error msg:Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address payable to bytes memory requested. This function requires a single bytes argument. Use abi.encodePacked(...) to obtain the pre-0.5.0 behaviour or abi.encode(...) to use ABI encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only error in your code ()

```
keccak256(msg.sender)
```

`keccak256` will return 32 bytes hash. but the address is 20 bytes. so instead of uint you should be using `uint160`

```
uint tmpData = uint160(keccak256(msg.sender))
```

Comment: uint tmpData = uint160(keccak256(msg.sender));
address batchNo = address(tmpData); Error:Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "uint160".                                                                                                Error:Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address payable to bytes memory requested. This function requires a single bytes argument. Use abi.encodePacked(...) to obtain the pre-0.5.0 behaviour or abi.encode(...) to use ABI encoding.